# wget download and outout based on list

Tags: list, wget

I have list of names and URLs like this:

```
first name
http://somewhere:port/pat/of/file.mp4
second name
http://somewhere:port/pat/of/file2.mp4
third name 
enter code here
http://somewhere:port/pat/of/file3.mp4
```

How can we get these files with wget, and name each file with the line before the URL?

i.e.: `third name` would contain data from `http://somewhere:port/pat/of/file3.mp4`

Thank you in Advance

Comment: which operating system?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
exec 4< input_file
while read name <&4 ; do
 read url <&4
 wget -O "$name" %url
done
```

If filenames contain special characters, space, etc is good to have them in file in double quotes.